# Send and Receive UDP packets in one app

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp, datagram

I need to write an application in Node.js which sends some UDP packets to a given IP address and Port as well as listening for UDP packets from the same IP and Port.
Other examples i have seen all seem to mention a Client and Server architecture with one side sending and the other receiving. I need to do both in one app.

My question is: Can i send and receive on the same socket or should i have one for each as below?

```
const Send= dgram.createSocket('udp4');
const Recieve= dgram.createSocket('udp4');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You only need one socket - it's possible to both send and receive on the same one.

However to be able to receive the socket will need to be "bound" to a local port using [`socket.bind()`](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_bind_options_callback).

Comment: thanks for that, do you know if that'll impact performance at all?

Comment: you probably won't get to handle 100s of thousands of packets per second like this (or evens 10s) but most folks don't need that level of throughput